# Dynamically populating array if less than initial value

Tags: c#-4.0

Here's the sample code that I'm currently doing.

```
string stringWithDelimiters = "Hello%there%people%of%the%world";
string[] vals = new string[30];
vals = stringWithDelimiters.Split('%');
```

From the code above, the length of `vals` will be 6. But is there a way to "force" the array to use all 30 by setting the value of the other variables to an empty string even if it's less than 30?

Answer (score 1):

`stringWithDelimiters.Split('%')` returns an array. If you assign it directly in `vals` it will replace the whole array you just created beforehand.

In order to keep your array, you'll have to insert each value from the array returned by the `Split` method into your `vals` array.

Try:

```
string stringWithDelimiters = "Hello%there%people%of%the%world";
string[] vals = new string[30];

for (int i = 0; i < vals.Length; i++)
    vals[i] = string.Empty;

var tmp = stringWithDelimiters.Split('%');

for (int i = 0; i < tmp.Length; i++)
    vals[i] = tmp[i];
```

Comment: You're right. As said, it will still perform a loop internally, but it's clearer. Didn't think of this method. Must be tired :p

Answer (score 1):

This way the array vals will always have 30 elements. First fill the array with 30 empty strings then fill it with the Data that you split. I hope this helped you.

```
        string stringWithDelimiters = "Hello%there%people%of%the%world";
        string[] vals = new string[30];
        string[] vals1 = new string[30];
        vals1 = stringWithDelimiters.Split('%');
        int valslength = vals1.Length;
        for (int k = 0; k < 30; k++)
        {
            vals[k] = "";
        }
        for (int m = 0; m < valslength; m++)
        {
            vals[m] = vals1[m];
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

`Array.Copy` is generally the fastest way to move elements from one array to another. This solution will copy the split array to the 30 length array, then fill the rest (if any) with empty strings. Also taking into account that the split array length could be more than 30 (or any length for that matter).

```
private static string[] GetFixedLengthSplitArray(string input)
{
    const int TargetLength = 30;

    string[] splitResult = input.Split('%');
    string[] values = new string[TargetLength];

    Array.Copy(splitResult, 0, values, 0, Math.Min(splitResult.Length, values.Length));

    for (int i = splitResult.Length; i < values.Length; i++)
    {
        values[i] = string.Empty;
    }
    return values;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered the fastest solution to this. (I'll use @X.L.Ant 's solution)

`tmp.CopyTo(vals, 0);`

Thanks guys! I'll placed a one up to his answer. :)